# Posting to a Facebook page from a .CFM file

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, access-token

Ok, I have been racking my brain over this, and I am digging myself deep into a hole of access tokens and cfhttp tags, so I need some help with this one.

My goal at the moment is simple (in words). I want the wall of my Facebook PAGE (not user) to reflect what is entered into a form on a .CFM file. Immediately I thought, oh, easy, I can just do an http post on submit. That worked fine. I used the access token I found on the Graph API Explorer and it posted to Facebook with no problem.

The problem is, the access token expires...

I realize that offline access is deprecated. So I went to the help page on Facebook for that, and now my problem is, pages dont have app_secrets, which is required to change the expiration time on an access_token. How can I continually renew my access token so that my .cfm page will constantly have access to my Facebook Page?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an app, you have the sercet bit for it, just check the top of the app's settings. :)

You can read more about "The deprecated offline_access" here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Comment: My problem with this is that I am not doing this straight from an app (in fact I just dont know how to use an app to post to a page). I have just been doing a straight HTTP post request from my .cfm page.